# Como habilitar e desabilitar links sucessivamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho cinco links, e inicialmente somente o primeiro link está habilitado. Quando esse primeiro link for clicado, eu quero que ele se auto desabilite e habilite o próximo, ou seja, o segundo link, e quando o segundo for clicado, que se auto desabilite e habilite o próximo, e assim sucessivamente.

No entanto, os links que já foram clicados quero que permaneçam desabilitados até chegar no ultimo link. Abaixo segue um inicio do que eu preciso:

```js
  window.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(){return false};
    }
    
    function desabilitar_link(){
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "Link desabilitado";
        document.getElementById('link').style.color = "grey";                 
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' id="link" onmouseup="desabilitar_link()"> Link habilitado </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' id="link2" onmouseup="desabilitar_link()"> Link habilitado </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' id="link3" onmouseup="desabilitar_link()"> Link habilitado </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' id="link4" onmouseup="desabilitar_link()"> Link habilitado </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' id="link5" onmouseup="desabilitar_link()"> Link habilitado </a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução via jQuery, veja se serve para você nesse fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gf60xdgt/4/

Note só que eu tive que colocar o id do primeiro link para "link1" para não ter que ficar fazendo uma verificação desnecessária de código ali no meio.

```js
//para tudo que o id comece com "link"
$('[id^=link]').click(function() {
  //verifica se tem a classe disabled
  if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    //pegamos o id atual
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //damos split para pegar o numero
    var linknumber = id.split('link');
    //somamos o número + 1
    var nextLink = '#link'.concat(parseInt(linknumber[1]) + 1);

    //removemos a classe do próximo
    $(nextLink).removeClass('disabled');
    //adicionamos nele
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
  }
  //se tiver não faz nada
  else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
/* serve só para estilizar o link */

.disabled {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' class='' id="link1"> Link habilitado </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link2"> Link habilitado </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link3"> Link habilitado </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link4"> Link habilitado </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com.br/" target='_blank' class='disabled' id="link5"> Link habilitado </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: perfeito!! Isso já resolve o meu problema KhaosDoctor. Valewww pela a ajuda!

Comment: KhaosDoctor, porem tem uma coisa. Executando nesse editor funciona beleza, mas em outro editor não funciona, adicionei o "jquery" mas mesmo assim não funciona. Vc sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Veja se apresenta algum erro no Inspect Element do Chrome ou outro navegador.

Comment: Qual é o editor que você está usando?

Comment: Eu uso o 1st Editor jscript pro, no entanto quando executo-o abre pelo o Chrome e mesmo salvando o arquivo no pc ainda dá omesmo problema. Ao incorporar esse código no meu site funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Pode ser uma limitação do próprio editor, tente usar o notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Outra maneira de resolver é desabilitar o link por meio da propriedade [**`pointer-events`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) das CSS com valor **`none`**. Sobre essa propriedade, no MDN é explicado que:

> *A propriedade CSS `pointer-events` permite aos autores controlarem sob qualquer circunstância (se houver) um elemento gráfico particular podendo ser o alvo ([**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)) do evento do mouse. Quando essa propriedade não é especificada, as mesmas características do valor `visiblePainted` é aplicada no conteúdo SVG.*

E sobre o valor **`none`**, a mesma fonte cita:

> *O elemento nunca é o alvo ([**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)) de eventos do mouse; contudo, os eventos do mouse podem direcionar seus elementos descendentes se esses descendentes tiverem algum outro valor configurado no `pointer-events`. Nessas circunstâncias, os eventos do mouse vão acionar eventos de escuta em seus elementos pai conforme apropriado no seu caminho de/para o descendente, durante as fases do evento captura/borbulha ([**`event.bubbles`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.bubbles))*.

O único ponto em que o uso dessa propriedade pode ser considerado um problema, dependendo de como está desenvolvendo o site, é que, segundo o [*Can I use*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) ela não funciona em links renderizados pelo Internet Explorer 11, exceto quando estes possuem `display` definido como `block` ou `inline-block`.

Para resolver o que foi perguntado, o snippet abaixo define todos os links com `pointer-events: none`, evitando que seja disparado qualquer evento do mouse.E com Javascript, atribui uma classe `active` ao link ativo, classe a qual define `pointer-events: auto` e torna o *link* "clicável".

```js
(function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a'),
      index = 0;

  /**
   * Remove a classe 'active' do link atual e move o índice para
   * o próximo elemento na lista de 'links'. Ao mover o índice, o
   * próximo elemento recebe a classe 'active'.
   *
   * Se o valor do índice chegar ao número total de links, ele será
   * zerado, voltando ao primeiro link da lista.
   */
  function handler(){
    links[index].classList.remove('active');

    index++;
    if (index === links.length) index = 0;

    links[index].classList.add('active');
  }
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    links[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);

})();
```

```css
nav a {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block; /* bug do IE11 */
  color: #ccc
}

nav a.active {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class='active' href='#'>Link A</a>
  <a href='#'>Link B</a>
  <a href='#'>Link C</a>
  <a href='#'>Link D</a>
  <a href='#'>Link E</a>
  <a href='#'>Link F</a>
  <a href='#'>Link G</a>
</nav>
```